# Is there a way to dynamically switch fields from a model in the JSON representation of an object?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I've got a JSON representation of an object along with the relevant model classes listed below. The two classes `MinionSettings` and `LeeSettings` are derived classes from a base abstract generic class.

```json
{
    "charSetting": {
        "minionSettings": {
            "key": "minionSettings",
            "value": [1,2,3]
        },
        "leeSettings": {
            "key": "leeSettings",
            "value": [
                {
                    "baseAD": 1,
                    "baseAP": 1,
                    "visible": true
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
public class CharacterSettingsWrapper
{
    public CharacterSettings CharSetting { get; set; }
}

public class CharacterSettings 
{
    public MinionSettings MinionSettings { get; set; }

    public LeeSettings LeeSettings { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class MinionSettings : CharacterSetting<List<int>>
{
    public MinionSettings()
    {
        Key = "minionSettings";
        Value = new List<int>();
    }
}

public class LeeSettings : CharacterSetting<List<LeeSetting>>
{
    public LeeSettings()
    {
        Key = "leeSettings";
        Value = new List<LeeSetting>();
    }
}
```

Is there any way to keep all the fields in the `CharacterSettings` class but have them removed from the JSON representation of the object while keeping the relevant key/value pair, so I'd like the JSON to look like below. If not, is there anything else that I could do to achieve this?

I've tried using my base abstract class but since its abstract, I can't make an instance of it so it doesn't quite work, and this data is being extracted from a JSON and then put into a relevant object which based on the derived classes (like the two classes `MinionSettings` and `LeeSettings`)

```json
{
   "charSetting":[
      {
         "key":"minionSettings",
         "value":[
            1,
            12,
            3
         ]
      },
      {
         "key":"leeSettings",
         "value":[
            {
               "baseAD":1,
               "baseAP":1,
               "visible":true
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Why not remove `Key` instead. Final XML would be a bit different but duplication would be eliminated. I don't see the purpose of `Key` property as it is the class name with an initial lowercase.

Comment: In your target JSON, how do you expect your deserialization to recognize each element of the `charSetting` array and instantiate the correct class? There is no information in the JSON that reveals which type is being used where.

Comment: @Matt: OP's target JSON doesn't just have an omitted property, it has a notably different structure.

Comment: @Flater - But then the question is misleading. It is asking to hide a field in JSON representation which is effectively the same as excluding the property for the output. So either the title of the question should be edited or the description text should match with the question.

Comment: @Matt: I surmise OP misspoke. The main difference between the initial/target JSON is the absence of two property names (but **not** the properties' values - which is the part you missed). In OP's defense, the confusion in the phrasing is easily brought to light by both posting an expected example of output and by stating _"have them removed from the JSON representation of the object **while keeping the relevant key/value pair**"_. I do agree that what OP explicitly asked was misleading at first sight, but there is sufficient information in the question to understand OP's intention.

Comment: I think you don't need the wrapper. And in the question the CharacterSettings aren't generic. To make them generic, just write `public class CharacterSettings<T> where T: class 
{
    public T Settings { get; set; } ...` and then for T you can either use MinionSettings or LeeSettings.

Comment: @Flater - Ok, tried to match the title with the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this problem purely by using `JObject` and `JArray` objects without the need to create and use any domain objects.

In the bellow code I've assumed that the nodes exist (to keep the code simple) but in production code please prefer `TryGetValue` ([Ref](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_TryGetValue.htm)) over the index operator ([Ref](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm)).

```
//Retrieve the nodes from the original json
var json = File.ReadAllText("sample.json");
var root = JObject.Parse(json);
var charSetting = root["charSetting"];
var minionSettings = charSetting["minionSettings"];
var leeSettings = charSetting["leeSettings"];

//Construct the new json based on the retrieved values
var newcharSetting = new JArray();
newcharSetting.Add(minionSettings);
newcharSetting.Add(leeSettings);
var newRoot = new JObject();
newRoot.Add("charSetting", newcharSetting);
Console.WriteLine(newRoot.ToString());
```

I also have to mention that this code heavily relies on the sample json's structure. So, it is not generic enough to handle any kind of structure which resembles to this.

The printed output would look like this:

```json
{
  "charSetting": [
    {
      "key": "minionSettings",
      "value": [
        1,
        2,
        3
      ]
    },
    {
      "key": "leeSettings",
      "value": [
        {
          "baseAD": 1,
          "baseAP": 1,
          "visible": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Note for readers: this does render the JSON un-deserializable as the deserializer has no idea what concrete types to use for these array elements.

Comment: @Flater I think the exact same applies for the OP's request. Does my understanding correct?

Comment: Yep. Wasn't meant as a critique on your answer but rather for readers who want to use this.